# Whenever a record sale owner(custom field) is changed, how can we remove the sharing record of previous sale owner(custom field)?

Tags: apex, trigger, sharing

I have a custom field on opportunity that is sale_owner__c. We can add sales user in that field. Whenever a record sale owner (custom field-sale_owner__c) is changed, we are also creating sharing record of that sale owner (custom field-sale_owner__c).

But, I also want to remove the sharing record of previous sale owner (custom field-sale_owner__c) whenever sales owner get changed.

how can we delete the sharing record of previous sale owner(custom field)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your issue, you could create a record trigger flow to locate the old sharing record and compare it with the new value.  If it is different, delete the sharing record.  A record trigger flow should be able to handle these requirements.

Comment: Hey @ty, I already have sharing logic written in after update trigger. I want deletion also in after trigger.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).